# Regex not retuning the expected results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem where I am using some regular expression patterns to identify key themes in my "Feedback" column.

I am using the following code:

```
# creating regex patterns
pattern1 = re.compile(r'respond query|email|fast response|email|response time|responses email slow|long time|longer response|respond quickly email')
pattern2 = re.compile(r'visibility honesty|honesty|transparency 
timescale|transparency|transparent')

# Assigning what should be the theme
patterns = {
re.compile(pattern1)  :  'Communication',
re.compile(pattern2)  :  'Transparency'
}
#create a function to use the patterns as input in the next step
def match_pattern(text):
    for pattern, result in patterns.items():
       if pattern.search(text):
         return result
    return ''
#Applying the function to my column
df['Feedback_Theme'] = df['Feedback'].apply(match_pattern)
```

Now the problem is that for my test feedback that says:

"Transparency is required in data but emails are not received on time",

the Feedback_Theme returned is "Transparency" whereas I was anticipating that the theme would be "Communication".
Now I understand that the "Communication" is returned due to "email" getting encountered first from the pattern1 regex but I want "Transparency" to be returned as the theme.

Is there a method that takes into account the priority order of a given word/phrase that when matches the regular expression should only return that and not get overridden by another regex?

How can I resolve this?

Comment: note that you have compiled the pattern twice. If you want to specify a priority then `patterns` might be set as a different data type. A dictionary or list will preserve order and a dictionary might allow additional values to be set per pattern such as a specific weight or priority.

Comment: So how should I resolve this then? Any ideas?

Comment: Note, that your current attempt doesn't even match transparency, as regexes are case sensitive by default.

Comment: @Django0602, can you share a reproducible example of your column (*in a tabular format*) and show the matching expected output ?

Comment: You want the name of the pattern that matches positionally first in your given string right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by priority you mean pattern was matched earlier, you'll need to evaluate every pattern and get the one, match for which started earlier.

It can be done with something like this:

```py
import re 
# creating regex patterns
pattern1 = re.compile(r'respond query|email|fast response|email|response time|responses email slow|long time|longer response|respond quickly email', re.I)
pattern2 = re.compile(r'visibility honesty|honesty|transparency|transparent', re.I)

# Assigning what should be the theme
patterns = {
    pattern1: 'Communication',
    pattern2: 'Transparency',
}

#create a function to use the patterns as input in the next step
def match_pattern(text):
    matches = {}
    for pattern, result in patterns.items():
        r = pattern.search(text)
        if r:
            matches[result] = r.start()
    if len(matches) == 0:
        return ''
    return min(matches, key=matches.get)


print(match_pattern('Transparency is required in data but emails are not received on time'))
# Transparency
```

Also notice, that if you can reasonably be sure that your patterns are always lower case, than you should remove `re.I` from `compile`, and apply search to `text.lower()`. It should increase performance of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```py
text = "Transparency is required in data but emails are not received on time"
```

And several patterns:

```py
patterns = [
    {"name": "Communication", "pattern": re.compile(r'respond query|email|fast response|email|response time|responses email slow|long time|longer response|respond quickly email', re.IGNORECASE)},
    {"name": "Transparency", "pattern": re.compile(r'visibility honesty|honesty|transparency timescale|transparency|transparent', re.IGNORECASE)},
]
```

You would like to apply these patterns and pick the one that matches earliest in you given string.

To do so, I would:

```py
import re
import sys

## -----------------------
#create a function to use the patterns as input in the next step
## -----------------------
def build_pattern_matcher():
    ## -----------------------
    # creating regex patterns
    ## -----------------------
    patterns = [
        {"name": "Communication", "pattern": re.compile(r'respond query|email|fast response|email|response time|responses email slow|long time|longer response|respond quickly email', re.IGNORECASE)},
        {"name": "Transparency", "pattern": re.compile(r'visibility honesty|honesty|transparency timescale|transparency|transparent', re.IGNORECASE)},
    ]
    ## -----------------------

    def matcher(text):
        first_name = ""
        first_offset = sys.maxsize
        for pattern in patterns:
            match = pattern["pattern"].search(text)
            if match and match.start() < first_offset:
                first_name = pattern["name"]
                first_offset = match.start()
        return first_name

    return matcher

pattern_matcher = build_pattern_matcher()
## -----------------------

## -----------------------
#Applying the function to my column
## -----------------------
text = "Transparency is required in data but emails are not received on time"
print(f"Theme: {pattern_matcher(text)}")
## -----------------------
```

This will give you:

```
Theme: Transparency
```

Comment: But my idea is to use these patterns and dynamically generate the Themes based on the matches I am receiving from my text rather than giving a priority order. I want the order of the words / combination of words in the feedback text to be used to return the requisite Theme based on pattern matching.. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Given these patterns what did you want to be returned?  Is pattern1 more important than pattern2? Are the items in each pattern prioritized in some way?

Comment: Ideally no, the patterns are not prioritized in any way. Assume that these are standalone patterns and when a certain part of feedback text is encountered and the order is completely dependent on the feedback text, the patterns should generate a theme. If this makes sense